# Change grouping column based on slicer selection - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, visualization, dynamic-columns

I have a data set and a mapping table as below.

[image]

In Power BI, I created a slicer dropdown containing words "Finance Lens" and "Business Lens",  This is created using table "Lens" and column "Lens Type"

Based on the selection, I want the grouping to change in the below visuals.

[image]

I created a new column as below :

```
 Selected_Lens = If(SELECTEDVALUE(Lens[LensType],"Business Lens")="Business Lens",MappingTable[Business Lens],MappingTable[Finance Lens])
```

But it is not working... Any idea would help.

Comment: Have you integrated Selected_Lens column into your measure while building it ?

Comment: I have not created measure, as it is not allowing me to include measures in the chart as legends or in the matrix as row...  I created a new column.   Of course the tables and relationships are established

Comment: please tell me where do those values in the matrix on the left come from ? You created a measure or from a numerical column?

Comment: On the Matrix the left column in "Business Lens" column (from Mapping Table)..  the top row is "Month" column the values are "Sales" column.      If I select finance lens in the slicer....  The left column should change to "Finance Lens" column (from mapping table)

Comment: I think You should use 'Fields Parameter'  for this task which is a new feature of May-2022 update of power bi. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Perfect 10/10...   However I'm not able to use that "Field Parameters" in the filter section...  Like if I dont want to display the "ignore" group in each case...  Do you know a way to do that...?

Comment: Please check this article. You will find what you are looking for. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-the-selectedvalue-function-in-dax/